# How to fill area bounded by two curves using tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to ask a question on how to shaded the area between two curves.

First of all the following is the code

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{THEOREM}
\newtheorem{proof}{PROOF}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{color}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
        axis x line=middle,    % put the x axis in the middle
        axis y line=middle,    % put the y axis in the middle
        axis line style={<->}, % arrows on the axis
        xlabel={$x$},          % default put x on x-axis
        ylabel={$y=\sqrt{-x+1}$},          % default put y on y-axis
        ticks=none
    }}
    % arrows as stealth fighters
    \tikzset{>=stealth}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-4,xmax=2,
        ymin=-1,ymax=3,
        ]
        \plot[name path=A, thick,samples=100,domain=-4:1] {sqrt(-1*x+1)};
        \plot[name path=B,thick,samples=100,domain=-4:1] {2};
        \addplot[fill=gray,opacity=.4,domain=0:1,samples=50] {sqrt(-1*x+1)}\closedcycle;
        %\addplot[fill=gray, domain=-3:0,opacity=0.4] fill between[of=A and B];
        \addplot+[mark=none,fill=gray,draw=black,domain=-3:0,opacity=0.4] {max(2-sqrt(-x+1),sqrt(-x+1))} \closedcycle;
        \node [below] at (axis cs: 0.2,0) {$O$};
        \draw[thick,dashed,brown] (axis cs:-3,0) -- (axis cs:-3,2);
        \node [below] at (axis cs: -3,0) {$-3$};
        \node [below] at (axis cs: 1,0) {$1$};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

So the above code generated the following plot.
I actually want the shaded area to be between the horizontal line(y=2) and the curve(y=\sqrt{-x+1}) on x=[-3,0], whereas it is just shading the area under the curve and the x-axis.

How do you achieve this?

[image: output]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please complete your example in order to make it compilable. "But I am having trouble with this" is not telling us so much. What have you tried, where are you stuck, what problems are you getting?

Comment: Sorry, it's my first time so I'm fiddling with things. Forgive me if this is a bit frustrating. Is what I am asking a bit clearer now?

Comment: No need for sorry. Much better like this.

Comment: See [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/set-operations-illustrated-with-venn-diagrams/) for Venn diagrams.

Comment: You have edited this question in such a way that it is now entirely different and existing answers now make no sense. You should roll this question back, accept an answer if appropriate and ask a new question if required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{THEOREM}
\newtheorem{proof}{PROOF}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{color}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
        axis x line=middle,    % put the x axis in the middle
        axis y line=middle,    % put the y axis in the middle
        axis line style={<->}, % arrows on the axis
        xlabel={$x$},          % default put x on x-axis
        ylabel={$y=\sqrt{-x+1}$},          % default put y on y-axis
        ticks=none
    }}
    % arrows as stealth fighters
    \tikzset{>=stealth}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-4,xmax=2,
        ymin=-1,ymax=3,
        ]
        \plot[name path=A, thick,samples=100,domain=-4:1] {sqrt(-1*x+1)};
        \plot[name path=B,thick,samples=100,domain=-4:1] {2};
        \addplot[fill=gray,opacity=0.4] fill between[of=A and B,split,soft clip={domain=-3:0},every segment no 0/.style={white},];
        \node [below] at (axis cs: 0.2,0) {$O$};
        \draw[thick,dashed,brown] (axis cs:-3,0) -- (axis cs:-3,2);
        \node [below] at (axis cs: -3,0) {$-3$};
        \node [below] at (axis cs: 1,0) {$1$};
        \node [above right] at (axis cs: 0,2) {$2$};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

To fill an area between curves, we could style the regions individually using `every segment no` and apply a `soft clip` if necessary as in your case [-3,0].

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
\addplot fill between[
  of = func and line,
  soft clip={domain=-3:0},
  every even segment/.style  = {gray,opacity=.4}
];
```

[image]

I cleaned up your code a bit. Here is a complete example:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
        axis x line=middle,    % put the x axis in the middle
        axis y line=middle,    % put the y axis in the middle
        axis line style={<->}, % arrows on the axis
    }}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel={$x$},              % default put x on x-axis
    ylabel={$y=\sqrt{-x+1}$},  % default put y on y-axis
    xtick={-3,0,1},
    ytick={2},
    samples=100,
    domain=-4:1,
    xmin=-4,xmax=2,
    ymin=-1,ymax=3,
  ]
  \addplot[name path=func, black, thick, mark=none, ] {sqrt(-x+1)};
  \addplot[name path=line,thick] {2};
  \addplot fill between[
    of = func and line,
    soft clip={domain=-3:0},
    every even segment/.style  = {gray,opacity=.4}
  ];
  \draw[thick,dashed,brown] (axis cs:-3,0) -- (axis cs:-3,2);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**BTW:**

You don't need nodes to place axis tick labels, use the `xtick` and `xtick` options instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `soft clip` to restrict the filling to the domain *x=[-3,0]*:

```
\addplot[fill=gray,opacity=0.4] fill between [of=A and B, soft clip={domain=-3:0}];
```

Thus the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
  axis x line=middle,    % put the x axis in the middle
  axis y line=middle,    % put the y axis in the middle
  axis line style={<->}, % arrows on the axis
  xlabel={$x$},          % default put x on x-axis
  ylabel={$y=\sqrt{-x+1}$},          % default put y on y-axis
  ticks=none
}}

% arrows as stealth fighters
\tikzset{>=stealth}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      xmin=-4,xmax=2,
      ymin=-1,ymax=3,
      ]
      \plot[name path=A, thick,samples=100,domain=-4:1] {sqrt(-1*x+1)};
      \plot[name path=B,thick,samples=100,domain=-4:1] {2};
      \addplot[fill=gray,opacity=0.4] fill between [of=A and B, soft clip={domain=-3:0}];
      \node [below] at (axis cs: 0.2,0) {$O$};
      \draw[thick,dashed,brown] (axis cs:-3,0) -- (axis cs:-3,2);
      \node [below] at (axis cs: -3,0) {$-3$};
      \node [below] at (axis cs: 1,0) {$1$};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

gives the output

[image: Output]